# updateSubnetReservedIPOptions failed validation error upon creating a VSI in IBM Cloud with Terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

When creating a VSI everything with terrafrom everything seems to be set-up correctly but it throws one engimatic error regarding the appointed internal IP address.

```json
Error: [ERROR] Error updating instance network interface reserved ip(): updateSubnetReservedIPOptions failed validation:
│ Key: 'UpdateSubnetReservedIPOptions.ID' Error:Field validation for 'ID' failed on the 'ne' tag
│ null
│ 
│ 
│   with module.vpc_workload.module.vsi_monitoring.ibm_is_instance.vsi,
│   on modules/create_vsi/vsi.tf line 1, in resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi":
│    1: resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi" {
```

The VSI and it's IP is set up and works correctly, but any subsequent `terraform apply`
that is done throws the error that the VSI instance is tainted. So it is a problem that needs to be solved in order to continue working on it.

Any idea what this could be? Perhaps a problem with the terraform-ibm-provider?

Tainted error:

```
  # module.vpc_workload.module.vsi_monitoring.ibm_is_instance.vsi is tainted, so must be replaced
-/+ resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi" {
      ~ availability_policy_host_failure  = "restart" -> (known after apply)
      ~ bandwidth                         = 4000 -> (known after apply)
      ~ crn                               = "crn:v1:bluemix:public:is:eu-de-3:a/c0ff1d00dc6f6f66adce030d4dfac132::instance:02d7_bd6e47cc-7256-4995-a65b-6982b8440167" -> (known after apply)
      + default_trusted_profile_auto_link = (known after apply)
      ~ disks                             = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ gpu                               = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                = "02d7_bd6e47cc-7256-4995-a65b-6982b8440167" -> (known after apply)
      ~ memory                            = 4 -> (known after apply)
      ~ metadata_service_enabled          = false -> (known after apply)
        name                              = "monitoring"
      ~ placement_target                  = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ resource_controller_url           = "https://cloud.ibm.com/vpc-ext/compute/vs" -> (known after apply)
      ~ resource_crn                      = "crn:v1:bluemix:public:is:eu-de-3:a/c0ff1d00dc6f6f66adce030d4dfac132::instance:02d7_bd6e47cc-7256-4995-a65b-6982b8440167" -> (known after apply)
      ~ resource_group_name               = "toolbox-fra" -> (known after apply)
      ~ resource_name                     = "monitoring" -> (known after apply)
      ~ resource_status                   = "running" -> (known after apply)
      ~ status                            = "running" -> (known after apply)
      ~ status_reasons                    = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ tags                              = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ total_network_bandwidth           = 3000 -> (known after apply)
      ~ total_volume_bandwidth            = 1000 -> (known after apply)
      ~ vcpu                              = [
          - {
              - architecture = "amd64"
              - count        = 2
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ volume_attachments                = [
          - {
              - id          = "02d7-630f0198-913e-4f66-9ca6-ec7cfc810077"
              - name        = "hybrid-probably-crayfish-tribute"
              - volume_crn  = "crn:v1:bluemix:public:is:eu-de-3:a/c0ff1d00dc6f6f66adce030d4dfac132::volume:r010-d1907aa9-9cf8-4ac6-9802-c898e13305e2"
              - volume_id   = "r010-d1907aa9-9cf8-4ac6-9802-c898e13305e2"
              - volume_name = "attach-earwig-crushable-decade"
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
```

Here's what I think is the relevant part of the vsi module

```
resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi" {
  name           = var.name
  image          = var.image_id
  profile        = var.profile
  vpc            = var.vpc_id
  zone           = var.availability_zone
  keys           = var.ssh_key_ids
  resource_group = var.resource_group_id

  primary_network_interface {
    name            = "eth0"
    subnet          = var.subnet_id
    security_groups = [var.security_group_id]

    primary_ip {
      address     = var.ipv4_address
      name        = "${var.name}-primary-ip-address"
      auto_delete = false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what does your module's block for creating the vsi looks like, i.e.

```
resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi" {
  ...
}
```

are you using a primary_ip block inside and is the name of the primary ip auto-generated?

```
primary_ip {
      name = "<some-value-that-changes>?"
}
```

Thank you for the edits and including the ibm_is_instance code block. I believe the problem is the way you are assigning the IP address (not saying that the provider should not be looking in fixing a few things, i.e. the primary_ip should have rejected unacceptable options), but the example that they provide for using the "primary_ip" section is when you are assigning a reserved IP.  If you are using a reserved IP you should not be specifying the IP address, but instead the ID for the reserved IP like so..

```
  primary_network_interface {
    name   = "eth0"
    subnet = ibm_is_subnet.example.id
    primary_ip {
      reserved_ip = ibm_is_subnet_reserved_ip.example.reserved_ip
    }
  }
```

If you want to specify an IP that is not reserved, but you believe is available to obtain, you can use

```
  primary_network_interface {
    subnet = ibm_is_subnet.example.id
    primary_ipv4_address = "10.240.0.6"
    allow_ip_spoofing = true
  }
```

You can find the examples in here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/is_instance#example-usage